# Ubuntu 19.04 is sluggish on good hardware

Tags: 19.04, performance

My system is very sluggish running the latest version of Ubuntu.
Websites are slow to load, programs startup slowly.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot / tweak ubuntu to make it faster?

Hardware:

- Ryzen 7 1700 (Not Overclocked)
- 16GB DDR4 Running at 3000 (2x8GB Corsair Vengeance LPX 3000)
- ASUS B450-i Motherboard
- 512GB Crucial MX300 M2.SATA
- AMD RX570 with 8GB
- Gigabit Ethernet

When I run the sensors command, I don't see any data related to my CPU.

Internet speed test came back at 282.6 Down / 17.7 Up.

I'm running the recommended BIOS from ASUS (2501). (newer bios versions are geared towards the new ryzen 3000 series processors)

I have completed a full run of memtest86 successfully. (This was the first thing I did after building the computer)

[image: SMART Screenshot]

Comment: Check if AHCI is enabled for SATA.

Comment: Then run `top` and `free` to discover the biggest CPU/RAM-using processes.

Comment: Was the same system running faster previously?

Comment: 4) Overclocking? Try dialing back down to no overclocking. 5) Two ea. 8GB memory or one ea. 16GB memory? If the former, remove one & retest; if no chance, switch out for the other & retest. 6) What's the make and model of the memory? 7) What does lm-sensors https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-check-cpu-temperature-on-ubuntu-linux/ tell you about the CPU temp?  Please click [edit] and answer 4-7 as well as the three questions above. Please avoid Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: I updated the question with the details you asked for. It looks like my CPU temperature is not detected. Could this be causing it to throttle and result in the slow behavior I'm seeing?

Comment: It is not a perfect idea to suggest everyone to upgrade BIOS. It may totally ruin the installation without an easy return if any. @heynnema

Comment: @ScArcher2 Is this issue still there?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 19.04 should be faster than 18.04 in general. The first thing I would look at, are drivers. Maybe for some of your hardware (network, graphics) are proprietary or different drivers available.

You can find additional proprietary drivers via: 
Application Drawer –> Software & Update –> Additional Drivers –> Install Suggested Drivers. If none are found, I would google for the best drivers of your hardware.

Other possibilities are: Maybe, many programs are started automatically? You can find by searching in the Application Drawer for "Startup Applications".

In general you can also use the activity monitor to find out if there are certain applications/services taking up a lot of resources.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I don't have any proprietary drivers available. I'm using an AMD graphics card which should have good open source drivers. I don't see any resource usage out of whack in activity monitor. I'm only using 3.5 GiB of 15.7 GiB of memory.

Comment: Then maybe you can try other desktop managers Gnome, KDE, Cinnamon, Mate, Xfce, Pantheon, i3, ... Just to see if its better with another one. Especially the websites load slow would be really strange because, if your internet is fine and you use a standard browser, there can not be much of an issue. At least nothing I can think of. Out of curiosity, maybe you can try some internet speed test and also some ssd speed test to see if there is something strange or unexpected slow...